# Google picasa deleted album

Tags: picasa

Using Google Picasa Web API, how do you determine if a photo album has been deleted?  I'm testing the API and in testing I have created several folders, have deleted them, and then I'm searching for folder by name and getting both active and deleted folders.  Is a deleted property available somewhere in the PicasEntry or other Album Accessor field?

Karl..

Comment: I've noticed that the order in which the albums are created seem to be the order in which they are fetched.  So for now, I'm going to go with a last one in "wins" rule on this.  I'm not marking this as an answer, and still hoping someone comes back with more details on the matter, but this is an acceptable work around.

Comment: As I know, there is no deleted property for the moment.  Actually, I think this is a bug.  This problem occur after the google photo using the same api with Picasa.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback michael.  Last in wins then.